# How do I put a variable in grep command to search?

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to `grep` for a word in a directory - but I want to check for numbers 1-9 in the word.

**This is a simple grep:**

```
grep -r L01auxillar /pr/solder/
```

I want the `grep` command to search: `grep -r L0[1-9]auxillar /pr/solder/`

Comment: your should know what is regex first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep regular expression for digits in character string of variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1863204/608639). And maybe questions like [Why doesn't \[01-12\] range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3148240/608639)

Comment: Always singe quote strings and scripts unless you have a **NEED** to use double quotes or no quotes. Just quote your string `grep -r 'L0[1-9]auxillar' /pr/solder/`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regexes within grep, you could do the number expansion in the shell:

```
grep -r --regexp=L0{1..9}auxillar /pr/solder/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just pass an -E for extended regex:**

```
grep -rE '(L0[1-9]auxillar)' /pr/solder/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wildcard for the one character.

```
grep -rn '/home/user/temp' -e '\<asd.f\>'
# use operator w if you want to catch whole words
grep -rnw '/home/user/temp' -e '\<asd.f\>'

Output:
/home/user/temp/test:1:asd4f
/home/user/temp/test:2:asd5f
```

But it would also give matches with other chars (eg asd0f or asdgf).